# Java- Giving strings in an array values, and ordering them from lowest to highest numerically

Tags: java, arrays, string, hashtable

Okay, so I have String arrays for a card project-

```
    String[] rank = {"A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9", "J", "Q","K"};
    String[] suit = {"H", "S", "D", "C"};
```

I am uncertain how I would go about ordering the strings "A-K"(1-13).. I'm attempting to use a Hashtable to multiply "suit" and "rank" together (this has created 52 "null" values..)

I am disregarding the "rank of the suits", like a 7 of spades has a greater value than a 7 of clubs (if that is true) haha.

I want to make it so when I print the hashtable, it displays "HA", "H2", "H3", so on..

Any pointers? And could I do it (correctly) the way I'm trying to go about it? Apologies for my inexperience, by the way :D I'm sure I'm missing some very obvious stuff...

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to achieve. Anyway, You should have two enums insted of Strings: an enum for Card values (A to K), and an enum for Card colors (H, S, D, C)

Answer (score 1):

First: DON'T use `Hashtable`, it's obsolete.

Second: create two enums; one for card "value", another for suite:

Value:

```
public enum CardValue {
    ONE("1"),
    TWO("2"),
    // etc
    KING("king"),
    ACE("ace")
    ;

    private final String asString;

    CardValue(final String asString)
    {
        this.asString = asString;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return asString;
    }
}
```

Suite:

```
public enum CardSuite
{
    CLUBS,
    DIAMONDS,
    HEARTS,
    SPADES
}
```

Then a Card:

```
public final class Card
    implements Comparable<Card>
{
    private final CardValue value;
    private final CardSuite suite;

    public Card(final CardValue value, final CardSuite suite)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.suite = suite;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return Objects.hashCode(value, suite);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        final Card other = (Card) obj;
        return suite == other.suite
            && value == other.value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final Card o)
    {
        final int ret = suite.compareTo(other.suite);
        return ret != 0 ? ret : value.compareTo(other.value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return value + " of " + suite.toString().toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

This will actually print "king of spades" for `new Card(CardValue.KING, CardSuite.SPADES)`; and as `Card` implements `Comparable`, you can use `.compareTo()` on each of them. In this implementations, a two of spades (`new Card(CardValue.TWO, CardSuite.SPADES)`) is considered greater than a jack of clubs (`new Card(CardValue.JACK, CardSuite.CLUBS)`).

Note that it relies on the fact that enums are comparable, and that the natural ordering is based on their declarations; that is, in:

```
public enum { FOO, BAR }
```

`FOO` is considered less than `BAR`; but in:

```
public enum { BAR, FOO }
```

it is the opposite. Refer to [`Enum`'s `.ordinal()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29) to understand why.

Note also that in `Card`'s `.equals()`, `==` is used instead of `.equals()` to compare instance variables; this is because all instance variables are enums, and enum values are all singletons.

Answer (score 0):

Consider implementing a Card helper class. The array values can then simply be enumerated in order of precedence and accessed by methods of the Card class.

Answer (score 0):

Suggested card class:

```
public class Card{
  /* these are the valid ranks and suits (both represented as Strings) */
  protected final static String[] RANKS = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
  protected final static String[] SUITS = {"Diamond", "Club", "Heart", "Spade" };

  protected int rank;
  protected String suit;

  /* required methods for all cards to have */
  public int getRank(){
    return rank;
  }

  public String getSuit(){
    return suit;
  }

  /* override Object's toString() */
  public final String toString(){
    return String.valueOf(this.getRank()) + String.valueOf(this.getSuit().charAt(0)); 
  }

  public Card(int rank, String suit){
    this.rank = rank;
    this.suit = suit;
  }

  public Card(String rank, String suit){
    for(int r = 0; r < RANKS.length; r+=1){
      if( rank.equals(RANKS[r]) ){
        this.rank = r+1;
      }
    }
    this.suit = suit;
  }
}
```

Would use this to define what a card IS. From this you can sort them using a compare method of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

create a `card` class and just build a a list of card objects. You can use `enum` as others suggested.

### Card Class:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Card
{
     string rank;
     string suit;
     public  Card(string s,string r)
     {
         rank = r;
         suit = s;
     }

     public void print()
     {
         Console.WriteLine(suit+rank);
     }
}
```

### Main Class:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


class CardBuilder
{
     static string[] rank = new string[]{"A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9", "J", "Q","K"};
     static string[] suit = new string[]{"H", "S", "D", "C"};

    public static List<Card> Cards;

    static void Main()
    {
        // Read in every line in the file.
        buildCardPack();
        print();
    }

    public static void buildCardPack()
    {
        Cards = new List<Card>();
        foreach(string s in suit)
        {
             foreach(string r in rank)
            {
                Cards.Add(new Card(s,r));
            }
        }
    }
    public static void print()
    {
        foreach(Card c in Cards)
        {
            c.print();
        }
    }

}
```